# All dates between two Date objects (Swift)

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I’m creating a date using `NSDateComponents()`.

```
let startDate = NSDateComponents()
startDate.year = 2015
startDate.month = 9
startDate.day = 1
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let startDateNSDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(startDate)!
```

... now I want to print all dates since the `startDate` until today, `NSDate()`. I’ve already tried playing with `NSCalendarUnit`, but it only outputs the whole difference, not the single dates between.

```
let unit: NSCalendarUnit = [.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second]
let diff = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(unit, fromDate: startDateNSDate, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
```

How can I print all dates between two `Date`objects?

**Edit 2019**

In the meantime the naming of the classes had changed – `NSDate` is now just `Date`. `NSDateComponents` is now called `DateComponents`. `NSCalendar.currentCalendar()` is now just `Calendar.current`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Just add one day unit to the date until it reaches
the current date (Swift 2 code):

```
var date = startDateNSDate // first date
let endDate = NSDate() // last date

// Formatter for printing the date, adjust it according to your needs:
let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
fmt.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

// While date <= endDate ...
while date.compare(endDate) != .OrderedDescending {
    print(fmt.stringFromDate(date))
    // Advance by one day:
    date = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: date, options: [])!
}
```

Update for **Swift 3:**

```
var date = startDate // first date
let endDate = Date() // last date

// Formatter for printing the date, adjust it according to your needs:
let fmt = DateFormatter()
fmt.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

while date <= endDate {
    print(fmt.string(from: date))
    date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)!
}
```

Comment: @Martin : i am getting this error "Binary operator '<=' cannot be applied to two 'NSDate' operands ". Please help me.

Comment: @Smita: Did you use the exact Swift 3 code from the second part in the answer? Did you define `date` and `endDate` as `Date` (and not `NSDate`) ?

Answer (score 51):

Using extension:

```
extension Date {
    static func dates(from fromDate: Date, to toDate: Date) -> [Date] {
        var dates: [Date] = []
        var date = fromDate
        
        while date <= toDate {
            dates.append(date)
            guard let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date) else { break }
            date = newDate
        }
        return dates
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let datesBetweenArray = Date.dates(from: Date(), to: Date())
```

Answer (score 9):

Same thing but prettier:

```
extension Date {

  func allDates(till endDate: Date) -> [Date] {
    var date = self
    var array: [Date] = []
    while date <= endDate {
      array.append(date)
      date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)!
    }
    return array
  }
}
```

How to get all dates for next 20 days:

```
if let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 20, to: Date()) {
  print(Date().allDates(till: date))
}
```

Comment: what is 'startDate' ?

Comment: @amin change Date() to your startDate

Comment: if let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 20, to: Date()) {
  print(Date().allDates(till: date))
}

  Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)!

Answer (score 5):

***Here is Solution of Print all dates between two Dates (Swift 4 Code)***

```
var mydates : [String] = []
var dateFrom =  Date() // First date
var dateTo = Date()   // Last date

// Formatter for printing the date, adjust it according to your needs:
let fmt = DateFormatter()
fmt.dateFormat = "yyy-MM-dd"
dateFrom = fmt.date(from: strstartDate)! // "2018-03-01"
dateTo = fmt.date(from: strendDate)! // "2018-03-05"


while dateFrom <= dateTo {
    mydates.append(fmt.string(from: dateFrom))
    dateFrom = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: dateFrom)!

}

print(mydates) // Your Result
```

Output is:

```
["2018-03-01", "2018-03-02", "2018-03-03", "2018-03-04", "2018-03-05"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your desired code becomes like

```
    let startDate = NSDateComponents()
    startDate.year = 2015
    startDate.month = 9
    startDate.day = 1
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let startDateNSDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(startDate)!


    var offsetComponents:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents();
    offsetComponents.day = 1
    var nd:NSDate = startDateNSDate;

    println(nd)
    while nd.timeIntervalSince1970 < NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 {
        nd = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(offsetComponents, toDate: nd, options: nil)!;
            println(nd)


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using this approach (Swift 3):

```
import Foundation

class Dates {
    static func printDatesBetweenInterval(_ startDate: Date, _ endDate: Date) {
        var startDate = startDate
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        let fmt = DateFormatter()
        fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

        while startDate <= endDate {
            print(fmt.string(from: startDate))
            startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate)!
        }
    }

    static func dateFromString(_ dateString: String) -> Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

        return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
    }
}
```

and I am calling this like:

```
Dates.printDatesBetweenInterval(Dates.dateFromString("2017-01-02"), Dates.dateFromString("2017-01-9"))
```

The output is:

```
2017-01-02
2017-01-03
2017-01-04
2017-01-05
2017-01-06
2017-01-07
2017-01-08
2017-01-09
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the compactMap operator.
I like to put these functions in an extension so they are reusable.
It's hard to make a range of dates, so I made a range of ints and loop through that.

```
extension Calendar {
    func getDates(_ startDate: Date, _ endDate: Date) -> [Date]  {
        // make sure parameters are valid
        guard startDate < endDate else { print("invalid parameters"); return [] }
        // how many days between dates?
        let dayDiff = Int(self.dateComponents([.day], from: startDate, to: endDate).day ?? 0)
        let rangeOfDaysFromStart: Range<Int> = 0..<dayDiff + 1
        let dates = rangeOfDaysFromStart.compactMap{ self.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0, to: startDate) }
        return dates
    }
}
```

Your usage could be:

```
let startDate = Date(dateString: "1/2/2017", format: "M/d/yyyy")
let endDate = Date(dateString: "1/9/2017", format: "M/d/yyyy")
let dates = Calendar.current.getDates(startDate, endDate)
let f = DateFormatter(withFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd", locale: "us_en")
print(dates.compactMap{f.string(from: $0)}.joined(separator: ", "))
```

output:

```
"2017-01-02, 2017-01-03, 2017-01-04, 2017-01-05, 2017-01-06, 2017-01-07, 2017-01-08, 2017-01-09"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let easy = DateInterval(start: date1, end: date2).days

let extended = Calendar.current.dateInterval(year: 2025, month: 5).days
```

```
extension DateInterval {

var days: [Date] {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let days = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: start, to: end).day ?? 0
    return Array(0...days).compactMap {
        calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0, to: start)
    }
}}
```

Please add to the current implementation of the function, how to write it better, perhaps:

```
extension Calendar {

func dateInterval(year: Int, month: Int?, extendedToWeek: Bool = false) -> DateInterval? {
    guard
        var start = date(from: DateComponents(year: year, month: month)),
        var interval = dateInterval(of: month != nil ? .month : .year, for: start),
        var end = date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: interval.end)
    else { return nil }
    
    if extendedToWeek {
        let component: Calendar.Component = month != nil ? .weekOfMonth : .weekOfYear
        start = dateInterval(of: component, for: start)?.start ?? start
        interval = dateInterval(of: component, for: end) ?? interval
        end = date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: interval.end) ?? end
    }
    return DateInterval(start: start, end: end)
}}
```

Interval aligned to weeks for a simple calendar. (extendedToWeek:)

[image: Interval aligned to weeks for a simple calendar. (extendedToWeek:)]