# How to get date range with a month of calendar with DateToolsSwift?

Tags: swift, date, calendar

So the purpose is to create a month view calendar with collection view. Today is the starting point, so I will get the first and last day of month in calendar from today.

```
func setDate(date: Date) {
    let firstDate = date.start(of: .month)
    let lastDate = date.end(of: .month)
}
```

Say today is **2017-07-19**, instead of first date return **25th of June** it return **30th of June** and last date return **31st of July** instead of **5th of August**.

I could solve this by using the pure Swift Date Library, but I believe that this task could be solved by DateTools. I just don't know how.

By the way I'm using Swift 3.
[DateTools Swift](https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools)

Comment: Is 25th of June/ 5th of August what you *expect* as result? Why?

Comment: You can find range (days) of two dates  hear https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536612/swift-print-all-dates-between-two-nsdate

Comment: @MartinR because in Calendar the start date of July 2017 is 25th of June not 1st of July. (Sunday is the first day of the week)

Comment: So what about calculating the start of month first, and use that to compute the start of the week?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, that is what I'm doing now, but I just want to know if the DateToolsSwift library already provided this solution.