# Create a time range having an initial time and ending time

Tags: ios, swift, time, range

I have variable **startTime** and **endTime**. In the **collectionCell** me need to display the **start time** and **end time**, but I need to between the **start time** and the **end time** was still the time **range**.

For example:

The day has 24 hours. My **startTime is 06:00** and my **endTime is 13:00.**
Me need to display **range** from **06:00** to **13:00** and in **collectionCell** i want to see it so:

**06:00**

**07:00**

**08:00**

**09:00**

**10:00**

**11:00**

**12:00**

**13:00**

Can I have it display? And how to do it?

My code:

```
var startTime: String = "06:00"
var endTime: String = "13:00"

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return // what need is there to write?
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeCell", for: indexPath) as! BookingTimeCell
    cell.timeLabel.text = // what need is there to write?
    return cell
}
```

Comment: This might help as a starting point: [Print all dates between two NSDate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536612/swift-print-all-dates-between-two-nsdate)

Comment: If you only have to display a range, just put your hours in one array using a for loop. In numberOfItemsInSection return yourArray.count, in cellForItemAt use cell.timeLabel.text 
 = yourArray[indexPath.item]

Comment: @AndreaToso thanks, i understand, but how to use loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programming often times is about breaking a large problem into smaller pieces. Here are the issues you were facing:

1. Your time is stored as a `String`. You can't add an hour to a string. Need to convert it into a `Date`
2. You need to generate an array of hours in between `startTime` and `endTime` and update this array whenever `startTime` or `endTime` changes.
3. Finally, show this array in the collection view.

Here's one way to do it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var startTime: String = "06:00"
    var endTime: String = "13:00"
    var timeRange = [String]()      // this array contains all the hours between your startTime and endTime

    // The formatter is responsible for converting a String to a Date and vice-versa
    var timeFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        return formatter
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Every time startTime and endTime change, reload the collection view
        // with a code block like this
        if let timeRange = generateTimeRange() {
            self.timeRange = timeRange
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        } else {
            // Handle error
        }

        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    // Call this function in viewDidLoad and whenever startTime or endTime change
    // Note this function returns an empty array if the time range crosses the day
    // boundary, for example: startTime = 22:00, endTime = 02:00
    func generateTimeRange() -> [String]? {
        var result = [String]()
        guard var startDate = timeFormatter.date(from: startTime) else { return nil }
        guard let endDate   = timeFormatter.date(from: endTime) else { return nil }

        while startDate <= endDate {
            result.append(timeFormatter.string(from: startDate))
            startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: startDate)!
        }

        return result
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return timeRange.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeCell", for: indexPath) as! BookingTimeCell
        cell.timeLabel.text = timeRange[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]