# Create string array of dates from Dates range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, date, date-range

I have `Date()` properties. `startingAt` and `endingAt`. And an array of Date(), which are `alreadyRegistred`. I have to create an array of strings with dates between `startingAt` and `endingAt`. `StartingAt` and `endingAt` are included and the last requirement is to exclude `alreadyRegistred` dates.

Do you have some elegant idea, how to do it? Thanks for help!

Edit: Maximum number of dates in final array will be about 7 days.

Comment: There are infinitely many `Date`s between two given `Date`s. – If you are thinking of *days* then this might help as a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536612/swift-print-all-dates-between-two-nsdate.

Comment: In this case, the maximum dates in the final array will be about 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget that a `Date` is basically just a timestamp, and that you can have access to the [addingTimeInterval(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1948745-addingtimeinterval) method.

Knowing that, is very easy to do some calculation between two dates.

I do not have the whole knowledge about your required business logic, but here is a naive implementation that generates `Dates` between two dates. I'm sure you can run it in a playground and explore a little bit.

```
import UIKit

func intervalDates(from startingDate:Date, to endDate:Date, with interval:TimeInterval) -> [Date] {
    guard interval > 0 else { return [] }

    var dates:[Date] = []
    var currentDate = startingDate

    while currentDate <= endDate {
        currentDate = currentDate.addingTimeInterval(interval)
        dates.append(currentDate)
    }

    return dates
}


let startingDate = Date() // now
let endDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3600 * 24 * 7) // one week from now
let intervalBetweenDates:TimeInterval = 3600 * 3// three hours

let dates:[Date] = intervalDates(from: startingDate, to: endDate, with: intervalBetweenDates)



let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .long

let dateStrings = dates.map{dateFormatter.string(from: $0)}

print("NOW : \(startingDate)")
for (index, string) in dateStrings.enumerated() {
    print("\(index) : \(string)")
}
print("END DATE : \(endDate)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see:

```
// Start & End date string
let startingAt = "01/01/2018"
let endingAt = "08/03/2018"

// Sample date formatter
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

// start and end date object from string dates
var startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: startingAt) ?? Date()
let endDate = dateFormatter.date(from: endingAt) ?? Date()

// String date array, to be excluded
let alreadyRegistred = ["01/01/2018", "15/01/2018", "10/02/2018", "20/02/2018", "05/03/2018"]

// Actual operational logic
var dateRange: [String] = []
while startDate <= endDate {
    let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: startDate)

    startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate) ?? Date()
    if (alreadyRegistred.contains(stringDate)) {
        continue
    } else {
        dateRange.append(stringDate)
    }

}

print("Resulting Array - \(dateRange)")
```

Here is result:

> Resulting Array - ["02/01/2018", "03/01/2018", "04/01/2018", "05/01/2018", "06/01/2018", "07/01/2018", "08/01/2018", "09/01/2018", "10/01/2018", "11/01/2018", "12/01/2018", "13/01/2018", "14/01/2018", "16/01/2018", "17/01/2018", "18/01/2018", "19/01/2018", "20/01/2018", "21/01/2018", "22/01/2018", "23/01/2018", "24/01/2018", "25/01/2018", "26/01/2018", "27/01/2018", "28/01/2018", "29/01/2018", "30/01/2018", "31/01/2018", "01/02/2018", "02/02/2018", "03/02/2018", "04/02/2018", "05/02/2018", "06/02/2018", "07/02/2018", "08/02/2018", "09/02/2018", "11/02/2018", "12/02/2018", "13/02/2018", "14/02/2018", "15/02/2018", "16/02/2018", "17/02/2018", "18/02/2018", "19/02/2018", "21/02/2018", "22/02/2018", "23/02/2018", "24/02/2018", "25/02/2018", "26/02/2018", "27/02/2018", "28/02/2018", "01/03/2018", "02/03/2018", "03/03/2018", "04/03/2018", "06/03/2018", "07/03/2018", "08/03/2018"]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
let startDate = Date()
let endDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(24*60*60*10) // i did this to get the end date for now
var stringdateArray = [String]()

if let days = getNumberofDays(date1: startDate, date2: endDate) {

    for i in 0...days-1 {
        let date = startDate.addingTimeInterval(Double(i)*24*3600)
        let stringDate =  getStringDate(fromDate: date, havingFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd")
        if !(alreadyRegisteredArray.contains(stringDate)) { // checking if already registered
          stringdateArray.append(stringDate)
       }

    }
}
```

and our helper method

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()


func getStringDate(fromDate: Date,havingFormat: String) -> String {

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = havingFormat
    dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
    dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
    let date =  dateFormatter.string(from: fromDate)
    return  date
}

func getNumberofDays(date1: Date, date2: Date) -> Int? {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.current

    let date1 = calendar.startOfDay(for: date1)
    let date2 = calendar.startOfDay(for: date2)

    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2)
    return components.day
}
```