# Swift 2 for loop low and high date between

Tags: swift, variables, swift2, nsdate

I have Array ;

```
var mydates             : [String] = []
let startDate           = "2018-03-01"
let endDate             = "2018-03-03"
```

And I have 3 variable , `startDate`, `endDate`, `dates` , i want to append that variables, like;

if `startDate` = 2018-03-01, and `endDate` = 2018-03-03

will be add **dates variable inside** =  "2018-03-01,2018-03-02,2018-03-03" between all dates from start and end dates.

How can i do it in swift 2 any idea ?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536612/swift-print-all-dates-between-two-nsdate and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169862/create-string-array-of-dates-from-dates-range

Answer (score 3):

Here is Solution for Print all dates between two Date **(Swift 4 Code)**

```
var mydates : [String] = []
let startDate = "2018-03-01"
let endDate   = "2018-03-05"

var dateFrom =  Date() // First date
var dateTo = Date()   // Last date

// Formatter for printing the date, adjust it according to your needs:
let fmt = DateFormatter()
fmt.dateFormat = "yyy-MM-dd"
dateFrom = fmt.date(from: startDate)!
dateTo = fmt.date(from: endDate)!


while dateFrom <= dateTo {
    mydates.append(fmt.string(from: dateFrom))
    dateFrom = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: dateFrom)!

}

print(mydates) // Your Result
```

Output is:

```
["2018-03-01", "2018-03-02", "2018-03-03", "2018-03-04", "2018-03-05"]
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer so others can understand what you have done.

Comment: @Lachie Now Check it :)