# How to Select Range - FSCalendar in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, fscalendar

I am trying to use [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar) in one of my project to selecting range of dates.

What I found is this library have Swift version however range selection version is only available with Objective-C. So what I tried to make is using bridging, however I am unable to use the [RangePickerViewController](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/blob/master/Example-Objc/RangePickerViewController.h) in Swift.

Did anyone implemented this library for Swift for using date range? (e.x. I want to select 2 dates as range for flight app where I am select Departure & Return flight dates.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Although FSCalendar does not directly supports range selection, it *does* allow multiple selections, which means that at some point you would be able to handle the range selection by yourself.

So, in the `viewDidLoad()` you have to make sure that you set the calendar `allowsMultipleSelection` property to `true`:

```
private weak var calendar: FSCalendar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    calendar.allowsMultipleSelection = true
}
```

The view controller should conform to [`FSCalendarDelegate`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/FSCalendar/2.7.2/Protocols/FSCalendarDelegate.html) protocol for handling the logic of selecting/deselecting a range.

What we need so far is to declare two dates for the range (the starting date and the ending date):

```
// first date in the range
private var firstDate: Date?
// last date in the range
private var lastDate: Date?
```

also an array of dates to hold value dates between `firstDate` and `lastDate`:

```
private var datesRange: [Date]?
```

and then implement the `didSelect date` and the `didDeselect date` delegate methods as:

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
    // nothing selected:
    if firstDate == nil {
        firstDate = date
        datesRange = [firstDate!]
        
        print("datesRange contains: \(datesRange!)")
        
        return
    }
    
    // only first date is selected:
    if firstDate != nil && lastDate == nil {
        // handle the case of if the last date is less than the first date:
        if date <= firstDate! {
            calendar.deselect(firstDate!)
            firstDate = date
            datesRange = [firstDate!]
            
            print("datesRange contains: \(datesRange!)")
            
            return
        }
        
        let range = datesRange(from: firstDate!, to: date)

        lastDate = range.last
        
        for d in range {
            calendar.select(d)
        }
        
        datesRange = range
        
        print("datesRange contains: \(datesRange!)")
        
        return
    }
    
    // both are selected:
    if firstDate != nil && lastDate != nil {
        for d in calendar.selectedDates {
            calendar.deselect(d)
        }
        
        lastDate = nil
        firstDate = nil
        
        datesRange = []
        
        print("datesRange contains: \(datesRange!)")
    }
}

func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didDeselect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
    // both are selected:
    
    // NOTE: the is a REDUANDENT CODE:
    if firstDate != nil && lastDate != nil {
        for d in calendar.selectedDates {
            calendar.deselect(d)
        }
        
        lastDate = nil
        firstDate = nil
        
        datesRange = []
        print("datesRange contains: \(datesRange!)")
    }
}
```

What about `datesRange` method?

I did not mention it in my answer for the purpose of making it shorter, all you have to do is to copy-paste it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49387351/5501940).

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer. I will look into it and get back to you.

Comment: do you have any idea what I can do to show 2 calendar in 1 screen? right now I have 1 month only showing...

Comment: @FahimParkar if you are aiming to add two calendars in the same view controller, you should check which one are you talking to in the delegate methods, by saying `if calendar === firstCalendar`

Comment: @FahimParkar glad to hear that 

Comment: @AhmadF, can you please help me on this : https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/issues/904

I am able to implement Range Picker by converting Objective C code to Swift but Start Date selection color is not changing until end date selection.

Comment: @AhmadF can your please help me regarding this : https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/issues/904

Comment: how to select range @AhmadF could u help me i m able to select only one date help me

Comment: @DilipTiwari have you followed my answer? if yes, what is the problem?

Comment: i tried i m getting error in 
  let range = datesRange(from: firstDate!, to: date)
error :- Cannot call value of non-function type '[Date]'

Comment: Instead of keeping an array of dates in the range, why not just check each date on the fly like `return date <= endDate && date >= startDate`

Comment: @AhmadF this works great. But i want to color the range of dates dates as shown in the output. How to achieve that??

Comment: Thankyou So Much Bro save my life

Answer (score 3):

```swift
class CalendarDelegate: NSObject, FSCalendarDelegate {
  
    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, shouldDeselect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) -> Bool {
        performDateDeselect(calendar, date: date)
        return true
    }
    
    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
        performDateSelection(calendar)
    }
    
    private func performDateDeselect(_ calendar: FSCalendar, date: Date) {
        let sorted = calendar.selectedDates.sorted { $0 < $1 }
        if let index = sorted.firstIndex(of: date)  {
            let deselectDates = Array(sorted[index...])
            calendar.deselectDates(deselectDates)
        }
    }
    
    private func performDateSelection(_ calendar: FSCalendar) {
        let sorted = calendar.selectedDates.sorted { $0 < $1 }
        if let firstDate = sorted.first, let lastDate = sorted.last {
            let ranges = datesRange(from: firstDate, to: lastDate)
            calendar.selectDates(ranges)
        }
    }
    
    func datesRange(from: Date, to: Date) -> [Date] {
        if from > to { return [Date]() }
        var tempDate = from
        var array = [tempDate]
        while tempDate < to {
            tempDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: tempDate)!
            array.append(tempDate)
        }
        return array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted @Ahmed F's code to Objective C.

Create following variables

```
NSDate *firstDate;
NSDate *lastDate;
NSMutableArray *datesRange;
```

add following line in viewDidLoad

```
datesRange = [NSMutableArray array];
calendar.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

and functions for FSCalendar

```
- (NSArray <NSDate *> *)datesRange:(NSDate *)from andTo:(NSDate *)to {
    if([from isLaterThan:to]) {
        return [NSArray array];
    }
    NSDate *tempDate = from;
    NSMutableArray <NSDate *> *arrDates = [NSMutableArray array];
    [arrDates addObject:tempDate];
    NSDateComponents *component = [[NSDateComponents  alloc] init];
    component.day = 1;
    while ([tempDate isEarlierThan:to]) {
        tempDate  = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:component toDate:tempDate options:0];
        [arrDates addObject:tempDate];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrDates];
}

- (void)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar didSelectDate:(NSDate *)date atMonthPosition:(FSCalendarMonthPosition)monthPosition {
    if (firstDate == nil) {
        firstDate = date;
        datesRange = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:firstDate];
        return;
    }
    
    if(firstDate != nil && lastDate == nil) {
        if ([date isEarlierThan:firstDate]) {
            [calendar deselectDate:firstDate];
            firstDate = date;
            datesRange = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:firstDate];
            return;
        }
        
        NSArray<NSDate *> *range = [self datesRange:firstDate andTo:date];
        lastDate = [range lastObject];
        
        for (NSDate *d in range) {
            [calendar selectDate:d];
        }
        datesRange = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:range];
        return;
    }
    
    if (firstDate != nil && lastDate != nil) {
        for (NSDate *d in calendar.selectedDates) {
            [calendar deselectDate:d];
        }
        lastDate = nil;
        firstDate = nil;
        [datesRange removeAllObjects];
    }
}

- (void)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar didDeselectDate:(NSDate *)date atMonthPosition:(FSCalendarMonthPosition)monthPosition {
    if (firstDate != nil && lastDate != nil) {
        for (NSDate *d in calendar.selectedDates) {
            [calendar deselectDate:d];
        }
        lastDate = nil;
        firstDate = nil;
        [datesRange removeAllObjects];
    }
}
```